# Is there a way to copy a single line of code but have it incrementally increase a number in said line of code for each paste?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I have a line of code I want to mass-paste into a file.

The line of code is `"enchantment.level.x": "string"`. I want to paste this multiple times into my program, but each time I paste the line, I want x to increase by one.

So if line 2000 is `"enchantment.level.1": "I"`, I would want line 2001 to be `"enchantment.level.2": "I"` (but I would change "I" to "II" manually).

Is there a way I can achieve this?
Thank you

Comment: also yes I am editing the "us_en.json" file from my Minecraft folder so that's why the line of code is such

Comment: you want Roman Numerals?

Comment: No. Why would a code editor support that sort of thing?

Comment: I do want roman numerals but I can change those manually @rioV8 -- I'm just trying to change x for each paste. I think I've got the right tool to do it but I'm still working with the developer of the extension to see what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to do what you want on each paste.  But if you make all your pastes first then you can @rioV8's or my extension to accomplish the same goal.

The extension is [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview) that I wrote.  It supports replacing with the match number (or index).  Put this keybinding into your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+m",
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": "(?<=enchantment\\.level\\.)x",   // match the "x"
    "replace": "${matchNumber}",              // replace with the matchNumber
    "isRegex": true
  }
}
```

You could make that into a named setting too if you don't want to run it from the Command Palette.

[image: matchNumber replace]

`${matchNumber}` starts at 1.  `${matchIndex}` starts at 0.

Comment: hmm, that didn't quite work, whenever I try to press alt+m nothing happens. Do I have to highlight the entire line or just "level.x"? and also, does there have to be space between the lines I want to change or can it work in consecutive lines?

Comment: You installed the extension first?  You do not have to highlight anything - the regex finds it.  The highlighting in the demo was just to show the before state.  It can work in consecutive lines or multiple occurrences on the same line wherever the regex matches.

Comment: I also forgot to mention copy that keybinding into your `keybindings.json` file.  From the Command Pallette, find and click on `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` and paste it just before the end of that file.

Comment: This did bring me to the keybindings.json file, but when I pasted the code into the json file it created a bunch of errors, saying "Incorrect type. Expected "object"" for "key", "command", "args", "find", "replace", and "isRegex". Along with this, it tells me to replace every colon with a comma-- is there something I missed or did I paste too much into the file? Thanks again

Comment: The keybindings.json file is one big JSON object so it should be wrapped in `{}` curly brackets.  Paste this keybinding inside the curly brackets.

Comment: oh my gosh that worked... Thank you so much for sticking with me to help me solve this issue!! Sorry that took so long btw I've never coded in json before. thank you :)

Comment: Glad it worked.  When you get 15+ rep points you should come back and upvote rioV8's and my answer - they are both good and took some time to develop the extensions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen) to generate the new numbers.

- Paste the line as often as you like
- Select the number on all the lines with Multiple Cursors
- use the extension and use `(.*)` for match regex and `{{=i+1}}` for generator expression